# opening files using with statemnt instead of assigning the open to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to learn how to deal with files through python3
so i reached this problem, where i couldn't know which part of my code is not working!
i am trying to print the contents of the same file twice using different ways, i believe that i have done multiple mistakes here,

```
file = open("exp.py", "w")
file.write("this has been written to a file")#it wil
print(file.read())
file.close()
print('first sanad')

with open("exp.py") as f:
        print(f.read())
        #it will be closed automatically
        print('second sanad')
        # f is a temp variable within the block
```

Error

```
36-32\writing to a file with w.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(file.read())
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Comment: Please do not post links, post code that we can read, and copy ourselves if necessary.  Is the `read` inside or outside the `with` block?

Comment: " the code is in the pic" do **not** post pictures of code, or even worse, links to images of code. Post code *as formatted text* in the question itself. It amazes me how often people decide that taking a screen-shot and uploading it is easier than copying-and-pasting text...

Comment: you are opening the file in `'w'`rite mode. you cannot read from files opened in that way.

Comment: i say calm down, its my first time, i appreciate it if you include an answer at the end instead of all these unnecessary  comments

Comment: @cdarke yes inside

Comment: When I run your code the error comes from the *first* read, not the one inside the `with` block as you imply from the question title.  The answer given by @AnythingIsFine should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue is, you are opening the file as write only, not as read write like so:

```
file = open("exp.py", "r+") # "r+" instead of "w"
```

[ ... ]

```
with open("exp.py") as f: ## here you should also specify "r+" if you plan to write to the file
```

[ ... ]

Please note:

Once you have called `.read()` on a file, you must call `.seek(0)`, otherwise it will print an empty string the 2nd time. Explanation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Comment: yet the first part doesn't print the contents of the file, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: As I specified in my initial answer, you have to call "f.seek (0)" after you have written to the file and then "f.read ()". Explanation is in the link I shared in my answer.

Comment: tamam, it worked, so after i writ or read i have to put the cursore up to read whats inside the file, or keep closing it and opening it, in this case with statement is usefule as it will close it when it finished.
Just explaining in details for the people who will read the question in the future.